# Open different view on the same viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, navigation, segue

I have implemented a third party menu, and when a user pressed on one of the categories, only the tableview (not the navigation bar or the menu, which are in a different viewcontroller) should change with a different view.

When I do a Modal segue, the navigation bar + menu are gone.
When I do a Push segue, my menu is gone + I want the user to stay on the "same page", not having to press the back button.

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this? Thanks in advance.

[image: Only the red squared part needs to change when you pressed one of the categories.]

Comment: Are all categories should view a tableView?

Comment: I have 15+ (only 2 are shown here) categories . When you press a category on the tableView, the red squared part should change to a different view (a UICollectionView which is already made)

Comment: Add a container and embed a unique ViewController for each item as u need it.

Comment: `UIView.transitionToView` would be your best bet.

Comment: Well then, to make it more easier than loading views from other viewControllers, you should add one collectionView and reload it when each category has been selected. Of course you will add the suitable cell for each category depends on how data should be presented.

Comment: try using `UIContainerView` that should solve your problem.

Comment: @NikhilManapure I placed my UITableViewController in a container, but I have no clue now how to segue to the UICollectionViewController ( What do I need to call in didSelectRowAtIndexPath) ?